# In android app the click is not working .when i click on this link.it must open in new window

Tags: javascript

In android app the click is not working . When I click on this link. It must open in new window.

This is my code.

```
<a href="#" data-url="http://www.google.com" class="navLink"><span class="icon icon-edit"></span>Website</a>
```

Comment: We can't tell why your JavaScript isn't doing what you expect unless you show us your JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript for this at all? What is wrong with just putting the link destination in the `href` attribute?

Comment: If you use `href="#"` then it links to a dummy anchor on the current page, or is that something you just substituted here? Or is there a script active, if so. what script?

Answer (score 1):

To open a link in a new tab you can use `target="_blank"` in HTML.

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" data-url="http://www.google.com" class="navLink"><span class="icon icon-edit"></span>Website</a>`

```html
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" data-url="http://www.google.com" class="navLink"><span class="icon icon-edit"></span>Website</a>
```

Comment: It'll work if it is a mobile browser, not sure about the app. you can still give a try since you are running html.